# How to Add Read Receipt Button in Dynamics CRM Email Form 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

In CRM 2011 form i need to add "Read Receipt" Button in "Email" Entity.When I check the "Fields" under the Email Entity the read Receipt button is available.

[image]

But I trying to Add this Field in Form ,there is no option to add.The Field can't able to view in Email Screen.How to Add the Read Receipt Button in CRM 2011 Email Form.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`readreceiptrequested` is a particular field, can't be added to the form and is not searchable through Advanced Find.

The field is used when an email is sent by the CRM 2011 Outlook Client.